# Removing ":" and characters after ":"

Tags: r

I am attempting to remove colons and and converts names to title case (as opposed to all caps) in R. Example of my data:

```
  LOCATION_NAME

  JORDAN: BAB-A-DARAA,AL-KARAK  
  TURKMENISTAN: W
```

Comment: So what's the desired output here? Did you try anything at all? We assume you've at least attempted to solve the problem on your own. Show your code and we might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Probably `sub("^(.*):.*$", tools::toTitleCase("\\1"), x)` but please look at MrFlick's comment re completing your example.

Comment: I mostly search to see what would be the proffered method. I attempted to use unlist(strsplit(readLines(textConnection(noaa_data$LOCATION_NAME),',')) and received incomplete expression error.

Comment: @Frank, That piece of code worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frank's suggestion worked.

```
sub("^(.*):.*$", tools::toTitleCase("\\1"), x)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could try something like this - first remove all the colons, then convert to initcap.

```
library('stringi')
mystring <- gsub(":","",mystring)
mystring <- stri_trans_totitle(mystring)
```

Comment: library('stringi')
mystring <- sub("^(.*):.*$", tools::toTitleCase("\\1"), noaa_data$LOCATION_NAME)
mystring <- stri_trans_totitle(mystring)